# If The Beginning Of A String Is Equal To Another

Tags: c#, string

i have a list that contains : `{"something1","something2","somefoo","bar"}`

I created a `foreach` loop to check for each string.

```
string input = "thing";
foreach(string word in list) //list = {"something1","something2","somefoo","bar"}
{
    if (word.StartContains(input))
          return;
}
```

So as you can see i want to check if my `input` string contains in the string in the list.
The result i want is i don't want to get returned in this code.

**What `StartContains` have to do ??**

This method needs to check if the first letters are equal to the input,
Not the entire word like what `Contains()` do.

I just have no idea to how to create this...

Thanks,

Comment: You need `word.StartsWith(input)` as far as I undestrand.

Comment: Does same thing as contains but compares starting at first character instead of any location in string.

Comment: Do you mean you need to implement something that does this and isn't built in? I know others have given you answers that use built in methods, but it isn't clear from your question if that's all you need or if you need to make your own.

Comment: @DigiFriend i thought there is no built method for this...
My question is solved :)

Comment: OK. Then you should read about all the string methods - I see others have linked to the documentation in their answre - read all of it, you will learn a lot.

Comment: From the list of words you provided, which should pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [String.StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Determines whether the beginning of this string instance matches the
>   specified string.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String.StartsWith("string")
```

In your example.

```
    string input = "thing";
    foreach(string word in list) //list = {"something1","something2","somefoo","bar"}
    {
        if (word.StartsWith(input))
        {
            // TODO: Do Something with the word here.
        }
    }
```

Here is a running sample to show off how it works. https://dotnetfiddle.net/mNVK1u

Answer (score 1):

The below will create you a list of all entries that match your input.

```
    var input = "som";

    var strings = new List<string>()
    {"something1","something2","somefoo","bar"};

    var stringsThatMatch = strings.Where(item => item.StartsWith(input)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
var list = new List<string>();
                list.Add("something1");
                list.Add("domething1");
                list.Add("romething1");
                list.Add("yomething1");
                string input = "thing";
                char[] inputchars = input.ToCharArray();
                foreach (string word in list) //list = {"something1","something2","somefoo","bar"}
                {
                    char[] characters = word.ToCharArray();

                    if (inputchars[0] == characters[0])
                        list.Remove(word);
                }
                return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, [String.StartsWith()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for.

But you could also create your own ExtensionMethod for that

```
public static bool StartsWith(this string baseString, string stringToFind, int lettersToMatch)
{        
    for(int i = 0; i < lettersToMatch; i++)
    {
        if(baseString[i] != stringToFind[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You then can call it like this:

```
bool startsWithMyName = "mynameisfelix".StartsWith("mynameisthomas", 8);  // true 
startsWithMyName = "mynameisfelix".StartsWith("mynameisthomas", 10);      // false
```

So you could simply ajust the amount of letters you want to match.